# remote shell auto completion suddenly off

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I have created multiple servers via ssh and one of them suddenly has no autocompletion and also doesn't support arrow keys up/down.

Also if I do `su username` from root my shell looks like this:

```
$
```

on the other servers it looks like this:

```
username@servername:~$
```

My steps on every server were the same:

```
ssh root@ip_address
password entry
useradd -m username
passwd username
usermod -a -G sudo username
su username
```

The systems are all Ubuntu `16.04` Does anybody know whats the issue?

**EDIT:**
By mistake the last server I have created was an Ubuntu `18.04` machine, which doesn't work correctly. So on the `16.04` machines the bash works fine.

Comment: `useradd` will assign you the default system shell. Check whether your shell is bash or just sh. In case of bash check that all of them have the same .bashrc file

Comment: I think the `.bashrc` is not being read. E.g. in my `.bashrc` the alias `ll` is definded, but if I write `ll` into the command line I get this `sh: 2: ll: not found`

Answer (score -1):

Also, make sure you have the following lines in your .bashrc (these should be there by default):

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Also I get `^[[A` and this `^[[B` shown if I click up or down key to repeat a command. What also is strange, that in my `.bashrc` the alias `ll` is definded, but if I write `ll` into the command line I get this `sh: 2: ll: not found
`